# Neo4j TransactionMemoryLimit

Tags: neo4j

I am running Neo4j (v4.1.5) community edition on a server node with 64GB RAM.
I set the heap size configuration as follows:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=31G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=31G
```

During the ingestion via bolt, I got the following error:

> {code: Neo.TransientError.General.TransactionMemoryLimit} {message:
> Can't allocate extra 512 bytes due to exceeding memory limit;
> used=2147483648, max=2147483648}

What I don't understand is that the `max` in the error message shows `2GB`, while I've set the initial and max heap size to `31GB`. Can someone help me understand how memory setting works in Neo4j?

Comment: Was the server running when you changed the config? If so, you have to restart it before the new config can take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the default transaction memory allocation for this version was `OFF_HEAP`. Meaning that all the transactions were executed off heap with 2GB max. Adding the following setting in Neo4j resolved the issue:

```
dbms.tx_state.memory_allocation=ON_HEAP
```

I'm not sure why `OFF_HEAP` is the default setting while Neo4j manual recommends `ON_HEAP` setting:

> When executing a transaction, Neo4j holds not yet committed data, the result, and intermediate states of the queries in memory. The size needed for this is very dependent on the nature of the usage of Neo4j. For example, long-running queries, or very complicated queries, are likely to require more memory. Some parts of the transactions can optionally be placed off-heap, but for the best performance, it is recommended to keep the default with everything on-heap.